# How to get selected column in JFace TreeViewer?

Tags: swt, jface

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH6gf.png)I am new to SWT Jfaces.
I am trying to create tree structure by using TreeViewer.

```
treeViewer.addSelectionChangedListener(new ISelectionChangedListener() {

            public void selectionChanged(final SelectionChangedEvent event) 
            {
                TreeSelection selection = (TreeSelection) event.getSelection();
```

How to get selected column from TreeSelection.

I need exact column which user selected.
If i used TableViewer getSelectionIndex() was there like that is there anything to get selected column.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tree and Table viewers don't really maintain a 'selected column' so there is no API for this.

If you want to edit column cells look at `EditingSupport` which does support separate editors for each column.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.  Actually if i select the one particular column in treeitem then only i need to do some operation.